# Add Shortcut in Context Menu Strip like ctrl+D1 and ctrl+numpad1

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu, keyboard-shortcuts

In my project i have `button` and i want set shortcut for button. Show i tried like this i create `context menu strip` add `tool strip` set shortcut. And call the `button click` event in tool strip `click event`, So now i can use that shortcut for my button. But Now i have problem i set the shortcut is like this `Ctrl+1` its work when i press `control + D1` but is not work in `Control + numpad1`. How to set the shortcut for tool strip menu using both terms.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If ((e.KeyCode = Keys.NumPad1 AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Or (e.KeyCode = Keys.D1 AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control)) Then


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. but i have doubt in contextmenu strip. i set shortcut for context menu strip cntrl+1. Its worked when i press cntrl+D1 but its not work when i press cntrl+numpad1.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by CTRL+D1? what is D1?

Comment: D1 means keycode of (1) D1. which is show in above the letters

Comment: k thanks james. But i have double can possible to those shortcut assign in single toolstrip. beacuse see my question i create toolstrip  for a button shortcut